# Is there a set of "Lorem ipsums" files for testing character encoding issues?

Tags: unit-testing, character-encoding, xunit

For layouting we have our famous "Lorem ipsum" text to test how it looks like.

What I am looking for is a set of files containing Text encoded with several different encodings that I can use in my JUnit tests to test some methods that are dealing with character encoding when reading text files.

Example:

Having a `ISO 8859-1` encoded test-file and a `Windows-1252` encoded test-file. The Windows-1252 have to trigger the differences in region 80<sub>16</sub> – 9F<sub>16</sub>. In other words it must contain at least one character of this region to distinguish it from ISO 8859-1.

Maybe the best set of test-files is that where the test-file for each encoding contains all its characters once. But maybe I am not aware of sth - we all like this encoding stuff, right? :-)

**Is there such a set of test-files for character-encoding issues out there?**

Comment: +1: I've just spent quite a bit of time implementing a UTF-8 decoder. Handling all the corner cases requires more unit tests than you might think.

Comment: "Text encoded with several different encodings": for good coverage you also want sample byte sequences that contain invalid bytes. According to the UTF-8 Wikipedia page, mishandling those cases has introduced security vulnerabilities in some high profile products.

Comment: @Raedwald Of course, that's a good point. I was not aware of this. In my opinion just one more reason for a mature test-suite for encoding issues. It does not have to be a set of files. It can also be a library providing test data that can be used in JUnit tests. For example it can provide critical/invalid byte sequences for common charsets and reference Strings for comparison after decoding sample byte sequences. Just some thoughts and I wonder how this encoding stuff got tested in all the libs around ...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

How about trying to use the [ICU](http://userguide.icu-project.org/) test suite files? I don't know if they are what you need for your test, but they seem to have pretty complete from/to UTF mapping files at least: [Link to the repo for ICU test files](http://source.icu-project.org/repos/icu/data/trunk/charset/data/ucm/)

Comment: +1 my favorite so far. I read in the documentation for 1 hour and it seem to provide everything I need - at least for unicode related stuff.

Comment: I think this is really the best answer so far. I accepted it and hope you'll get some reputation for it. If answered a week earlier I am sure it would have scored much better in comparison to other answers here. Anyway thanks!

Answer (score 42):

The Wikipedia article on [diacritics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritic) is pretty comprehensive, unfortunately you have to extract these characters manually. Also there might exist some mnemonics for each language. For instance in Polish we use:

> Zażółć gęślą jaźń

which contains all 9 Polish diacritics in one correct sentence. Another useful search hint are [pangrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pangram): *sentences using every letter of the alphabet at least once*:

> - in Spanish, "*El veloz murciélago hindú comía feliz cardillo y kiwi. La cigüeña tocaba el saxofón detrás del palenque de paja.*" (all 27 letters and diacritics).
> - in Russian, "*Съешь же ещё этих мягких французских булок, да выпей чаю*" (all 33 Russian Cyrillic alphabet letters).

[List of pangrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_pangrams) contains an exhaustive summary. Anyone care to wrap this in a simple:

```
public interface NationalCharacters {
  String spanish();
  String russian();
  //...
}
```

library?

Comment: For sure this is a +1 answer. I'll wait a bit in hope that there is really a well-thought set of test-files out there. Because there are encodings build on top of others etc. I think it would be very good having test files for each encoding triggering the differences. But maybe I am wrong and there are good reasons why they do not exist or so.

Answer (score 8):

I don't know of any complete text documents, but if you can start with a simple overview of all character sets there are some files available at the [ftp.unicode.org server](ftp://ftp.unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/)

Here's WINDOWS-1252 for example. The first column is the hexadecimal character value, and the second the unicode value.

ftp://ftp.unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/VENDORS/MICSFT/WINDOWS/CP1250.TXT

Comment: +1 Thanks for your effort. Very interesting resource of files.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few ready-to-use comprehensive unicode setups **straight-forward downloadable**.

## From w3c

Here, there's a nice test file **by w3.org** including: maths, linguistics, Greek, Georgian, Russian, Thai, Runes, Braille among many others in a single file:

- https://www.w3.org/2001/06/utf-8-test/UTF-8-demo.html

Coming from w3.org should be nice to use, shouldn't it?

#### Cutting out the HTML part

If you want to get the "original txt file" without risk of your editor messing it up, 1) download, 2) tail+head it, 3) Check with a diff:

```
wget https://www.w3.org/2001/06/utf-8-test/UTF-8-demo.html
tail +8 UTF-8-demo.html | head -n -3 > UTF-8-demo.txt
diff UTF-8-demo.html UTF-8-demo.txt
```

This generates a `UTF-8-demo.txt` without human intervention and without risk of loosing data.

#### More from w3c

There are many more files one level up in the directory structure, still inside the dir `utf-8-test`:

- https://www.w3.org/2001/06/utf-8-test/

## From github

There's a very interesting file here too with ALL printable chars (including Chinese, Braille, Arab, etc.)

- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bits/UTF-8-Unicode-Test-Documents/master/UTF-8_sequence_separated/utf8_sequence_0-0x10ffff_assigned_printable.txt

#### Want also non printable characters?

There are also many more test files in the same repo:

- https://github.com/bits/UTF-8-Unicode-Test-Documents

and also a generator if you don't trust the committed file and you want to generate it by yourself.

## My personal choice

I have decided that for my projects I'll start with 2 files: The specific one I pointed out from w3c and the specific one I pointed out from the github repo by bits.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I had used an online tool to create my text char sets from Lorem Ipsum. I believe it can help you. I dont have one which has all the different charsets in a single page.

[http://generator.lorem-ipsum.info](http://generator.lorem-ipsum.info/)/

Comment: *Lorem ipsum* consist of only Latin characters, as it is in Latin. This is not what is being asked here. BTW: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codeswarm/lipsum/1.0/